# PySide: Have an SVG image follow mouse without drag and drop?

Tags: svg, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to place an SVG image in what will eventually be a QGroupBox in another application. Then, upon the first click over the SVG, the SVG "sticks" to the mouse (as if the mouse button was held down during a drag and drop). A second click will release ("drop") the image.

I've been reading but not quite understanding the nature of / relationship between Widgets, Items, Scenes and Views. My code below sort of works but isn't quite right. The image almost actively avoids the mouse. Is there a clear explanation somewhere for non-C, non-C++, beginners with PyQt / PySide? Or is there a simple explanation for where I've gone wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui  import *
from PySide.QtSvg  import *


class Image(QGraphicsSvgItem):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Image, self).__init__("image.svg", parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable |
                      QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

        self.setAcceptsHoverEvents(True)

        self.svgSize  = self.renderer().defaultSize()
        self.width    = self.svgSize.width()
        self.height   = self.svgSize.height()
        self.absolute = None  # Image's absolute (global) position
        self.mobile   = 0     # Initially immobile
        self.scene    = None  # Not in a scene yet
        self.view     = None  # Not in a view yet

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        print "Enter"

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        print "Leave"

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        print "Moving"
        self.absolute = QCursor.pos()
        if self.view:
            relative = self.view.mapFromGlobal(self.absolute)
            if self.mobile:
#               self.setPos(relative)
                self.setPos(self.absolute)


class Viewport(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Viewport, self).__init__(parent)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.image = Image()
        self.image.setPos(100, 100)
        self.scene.addItem(self.image)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.image.scene = self.scene
        self.image.view  = self

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(Viewport, self).mousePressEvent(event)

        self.image.mobile = (self.image.mobile + 1) % 2  # Toggle mobility

        x = self.image.x()  # + int(self.image.width  / 2)
        y = self.image.y()  # + int(self.image.height / 2)
        QCursor.setPos(x, y)

        relative = self.mapFromGlobal(self.image.absolute)

        print "absolute.x() = {0}  absolute.y() = {1}"\
              .format(self.image.absolute.x(), self.image.absolute.y())

        print "relative.x() = {0}  relative.y() = {1}"\
              .format(relative.x(), relative.y())


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.view = Viewport(self)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.view)

        self.setLayout(hbox)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jukka on the PySide mailing list was able to help me out with the following response:

> You don’t have to do anything in `QGraphicsView`, you can have
>   `mousePressEvent` in `Image` to toggle floating on and off. These
>   events get QGraphicsMouseEvents as parameters and these have the
>   information you need about position of cursor or mouse press. So, in
>   short, remove `mousePressEvent` from `Viewport` and replace
>   `hoverMoveEvent` in your `Image` with this and it will work:

```
def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self.mobile:
        print("Moving")
        self.setPos(event.scenePos() - QPoint(self.width / 2, self.height / 2))

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.mobile = not self.mobile # Toggle mobility
    super().mousePressEvent(event)
```